# How to import build.gradle into IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

**NOTE:** Full source code for this [is here](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/intellij-scala-gradle-example).

I used the Gradle Init plugin to create a Scala library:

```
gradle init --type scala-library
```

Then I modified its `build.gradle` to generate a wrapper for Gradle 2.13. Then I ran:

```
gradle wrapper
```

To generate the wrapper. And then finally I ran:

```
./gradlew clean idea
```

I opened this project in IntelliJ Community. I modified the `Library.scala` (that the Gradle Init plugin creates) to contain obvious Scala compiler errors, but noticed the errors weren't showing up in red underlines:

[image]

I then right-clicked the `src/main/scala` directory and noticed there's no options for adding packages of Scala source files. Or any JVM (`.java`, etc.) files for that matter:

[image]

I think either the Gradle Init plugin is flawed (for `scala-library` types at least) or the Gradle IDEA plugin is flawed. Either way, I think I'm missing something in one of my IntelliJ project files:

- IML; or
- IPR; or
- IWS

Any ideas what I can change so that IntelliJ displays compiler errors and so that I can add new Scala source files?

Comment: `gradle idea` is obsolete and using it is not recommended, it will not generate the correct IDE project files. Instead, just import `build.gradle` in IDEA.

Comment: Thanks for the info @CrazyCoder (+1) - can you do this (import `build.gradle` to an existing IntelliJ project, or should I delete the project (in IntelliJ; *not* the file system) and do something different? Is this approach documented anywhere? Thanks again!

Comment: Delete any generated project files, then import `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks again @CrazyCoder (+1) - so I deleted the generated project files, and then I right-click the project root directory, but do not see any "*Import `build.gradle`*" option in the menu, or anything that even looks like that. Any ideas as to what this import option is called, or how/where I can find it? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) It seems you don't have a project JDK. That doesn't help. 2) The directory isn't marked as a source dir, so you won't see New Class. 3) Don't use `gradle idea`, just create the wrapper and open the dir with IntelliJ 'Open' 4) Why this old version of Gradle (Gradle is at 3.x)?

Comment: Import option is available from the Welcome Screen. Close the project, delete the files, Import.

Comment: Or just Open | `build.gradle`, works like Import in this case.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder that worked! By chance I perused the Gradle docs and IntelliJ docs hi and lo and can't find any official announcement of the deprecration of the Gradle IDEA plugin. Can you point me to any announcements, press releases, or articles that might document when this all happened (and why)? Just curious! Thanks again!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `gradle idea` command to generate IntelliJ IDEA project files is not recommended, it creates legacy format project files and in most cases the project will not work correctly (it will work only for basic Java projects).

This way of generating IntelliJ IDEA projects is deprecated and you should just open `build.gradle` file in IntelliJ IDEA (it's the same as using Import and specifying the build file location).

Mapping Gradle project model to IntelliJ IDEA project model is really complicated and is being maintained and supported by JetBrains developers using Gradle API, while `gradle idea` was added by Gradle developers and is no longer actively maintained.

Comment: Even if it would be deprecated, which is nowhere mentioned, not on the user guide, not on the DSL docs, not on the JavaDoc, it is still absolutely needed. Simply importing the `build.gradle` file will only work on pretty standard projects that don't have additional requirements. Our project would never work correctly in IDEA by only importing `build.gradle` (I know it, I tried) and you have no chance to customize

Comment: the process like defining that provided libs should be exported, defining source folders as generated, adding facets, adding configuration for plugins like SonarQube, defining VCS settings, generating run configurations, generating code style settings, setting encoding options, setting compiler options, setting copyright options, setting issue navigation options and other stuff, to just name a "few".

Comment: You will still need to use the gradle idea plugin if you also want to use the gradle play plugin. Intellij's gradle support does not work with the play plugin -- importing the gradle project directly will corrupt your project structure.