# Is it possible to configure file types mapping in Idea via gradle 'idea' plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

A little intro:

I work on a project with legacy codebase witch uses internal xml based descriptors with specific file extensions (about may be 10 extensions).
Let it be *.desc, *.check etc.

To have code highlighting for such a files I can configure Idea to consider these types of files as XML.

It's available through:

> Preferences / Editor / File types
>
> And then add all custom extensions to 'Recognized file types': 'XML'

Our project uses gradle as build tool

and **my question is:**

Is it possible to make same configuration via dsl of gadle 'idea' plugin?

Comment: afaik intellij has support for gradle via a specific plugin

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **No**.

One could create a custom Gradle task that will modify IDE file type preferences XML file in the [config directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519). While it's [possible to run such task automatically](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203373890-Calling-a-Gradle-task-when-idea-refreshes-the-project?page=1#community_comment_203710644) on the project refresh in IntelliJ IDEA, it will most likely not work since you can't modify IDE configuration when IDE is running (the changes will be reverted). So, you will have to run it from the command line, outside of IntelliJ IDEA when IDE is not running.

It's probably not what you want, but if documented, can be used by the team as the manual step to make this configuration change easier.

Using `gradle idea` is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891) anyway.

A better way might be to provide your own IDE plug-in that will associate these file extensions with XML file type and instruct the team to install this plug-in.