# Command line generation of IntelliJ IDEA project files?

Tags: intellij-idea

I prefer having one IDEA project per task I'm working on. If it's a Gradle project, I can run `gradlew idea` to generate the project files then rename them to be indicative of the task I'm working on (so that when re-opening from IDEA a project, it's obvious what the task is and IDEA is able to list several tasks for the same Gradle project). This works well enough if it's a Gradle project, but if it's not, I'm left with using the IDEA GUI to open the project by pointing to the working directory. Is there a command-line way to generate the IDEA project files so I can rename them prior to using the GUI? Being able to do this would also obviate the need for using `gradlew idea` for this purpose.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has no option to generate projects from the command line. Using `gradle idea` is also not recommended, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891) why.

Answer (score 0):

Using the GUI, create the project by pointing it to the `build.gradle` file or project root directory. Once the project is created:

- click the `File` menu
- click the `Project Structure` menu item
- change the `Project name` text value