# Using Gradle for Scala and ScalaTest (IntelliJ 2016.3.6)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle, scalatest

Here is a quick `build.gradle` file I put together:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.2"
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.2"
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.0.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

If understood correctly, when running `gradle idea`, the external dependencies defined above appear in the `External Libraries` folder.

While I do see the dependencies in the folder, the issue I am facing is that I am unable to import anything from my external libraries provided by Gradle. Anything I manually provide (i.e. a downloaded version of the Scala SDK) works perfectly fine.

I have `src` and `test` marked as my sources root and test sources root, respectively.

What could possibly be the issue? Detailed explanations are also appreciated; I'm coming from a Maven background and struggling with the Gradle documentation.

Comment: Don't use `gradle idea`, [see here why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891).

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder, I'll give the alternative a try