# Gradle Idea plugin support incremental build

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, incremental-build

I know that gradle can support java incremental compilation. But I don't see idea plugin support incremental compilation.

Comment: Please clarify the question. IntelliJ IDEA imports Gradle project and converts it into its own project model which is compiled incrementally using built-in compile server (JPS). IntelliJ IDEA manages its own compiler caches and tracks the dependencies, it also supports compiling different modules in parallel. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for reply @CrazyCoder. My question is that how can I have incremental compilation feature if I run gradle idea?

Comment: I read this blog:https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance. This flag doesn't work if I run gradle idea. @CrazyCoder

Comment: Using `gradle idea` is not recommended, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891. Why do you want to run it?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Very helpful. In my use case, I have lots of apps built by gradle. Lots of devs checks in the code on these apps. We want to have incremental compilation feature for our gradle so that build time is faster. Any recommendations on my use case?

Comment: You either build with Gradle which already supports incremental compilation (as you said yourself) or you build with IntelliJ IDEA a project that was imported from Gradle and which will be compiled using built-in incremental compiler. So, I still don't understand what is the problem.