# IntelliJ can't find slf4j logger with gradle

Tags: java, android-studio, slf4j

I have a project for which I use gradle, and I wanted to use the logger slf4j provides.

Running in Android Studio produces the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.mypkg.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

My build.gradle for the project:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.5'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "Main"
    }
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles('META-INF/spring.*')
}


mainClassName = 'com.mypkg.Main'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-ws:2.7.4'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'org.scream3r:jssc:2.8.0'

    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3'

    compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.shell', name: 'spring-shell', version: '1.2.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '4.2.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.2.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.25'


}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

If I build this project with gradle, the shadow plugin generates a fat jar, which runs from the console nicely, it includes the logger, but from the IDE I'm having difficulties finding the LoggerFactory. I read here that I should add the logger to the classpath but since I don't explicitly include a jar, rather than marking it as a dependency, I'm not sure how this would be possible.

Please advise.
Cheers!

Comment: script `apply plugin: 'idea'` alt+f12 and run `gradle idea` this will regenerate the .iml files and classpaths. Or try to install newest version of IntelliJ where the gradle integration is a bit better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classpath is out of sync, few options here

- Refresh the project in IntelliJ (the older versions of IntelliJ are not ideal with gradle integration)
- add `apply plugin: 'idea'` to your build.gradle and then run `gradle idea` to regenerate `.iml` `.ipr` `.iws` files in your project and pick up dependencies from gradle.(**Not ideal!** [see why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891))
- Download latest version of IntelliJ and redo option 1

Edit: Thanks @CrazyCoder for this hint.

Comment: I accepted this answer but I'm a little biased about it, as it wasn't the exact answer but it led me to it. First of all, I incorrectly marked the question as intellij-idea, although in the question I told I was using android studio. You mentioned refreshing, but I had the latest version of android studio, so I thought crawling around on their site, then I gave it a try with idea, which had no issues running my project without any changes whatsoever.
Cheers :)

Comment: Don't use `gradle idea`, [see here why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891).

Comment: Hi.  What does "refresh the project in intelliJ" .. mean.. ?  I have clicked and went to menu items and cannot find this magic.  I know it is probably something silly, but I'm stuck.

Comment: @granadaCoder what's the issue? Refresh means wait a couple of secs or hit F5

Comment: @granadaCoder I believe the leftmost icon in the right hand gradle panel which depicts two circling arrows is what is being referred to. At the time of writing it's labelled "Reload all Gradle projects".