# Intellij freezes during indexing

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working with a relatively large code repo that need to be all loaded into Intellij.  Recently Intellij hangs for long time (> 30 mins) to update the index after reloading the gradle files.
Is there any workaround?

Stacktrace during the freeze:

```
at gnu.trove.TObjectHash.insertionIndex(TObjectHash.java:262)
    at gnu.trove.THashMap.put(THashMap.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.putNode(ObjectTree.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.createNodeFor(ObjectTree.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.register(ObjectTree.java:78)
    - locked <0x00000007a2505f00> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.register(Disposer.java:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.register(Disposer.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.VirtualFilePointerManagerImpl.registerContainer(VirtualFilePointerManagerImpl.java:366)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.VirtualFilePointerManagerImpl.createContainer(VirtualFilePointerManagerImpl.java:358)
    - locked <0x00000007a1710270> (a com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.VirtualFilePointerManagerImpl)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.VirtualFilePointerManagerImpl.createContainer(VirtualFilePointerManagerImpl.java:352)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryImpl.initRoots(LibraryImpl.java:276)
```

Comment: Increase heap size - Xmx VM option

Comment: Or https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: I am having the same problem when we recreate the project files via "gradle idea" in a large project, unfortunately IDEA support denied my support request for this with the answer: "Using gradle idea is not recommended, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891"

Answer (score 0):

Are you excluding your bin, dist, or www folders from re-indexing themselves?

Right click any of the directories -> Mark directory as -> Excluded.

Comment: Yep, they are already excluded.  It is a fairly large source repo.

Comment: I would probably recomend trying VSCode  https://code.visualstudio.com/.. I've found it can preform better on large projects sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things. The biggest performance improvement turned out to be clearing up my SSD disk. SSD become much slower as it gets closer to full.