# Unresolved reference in regards to a gradle dependency?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I have the following maven repo listen in my gradle build file,

```
maven {
    url 'https://nexus.company.com/repository/maven-company-releases'

    // Omitting the credentials block for brevity.
}
```

and, in my dependencies I have the following.

```
compile "com.company:dependency:0.0.1"
```

Now, when I do

```
gradle clean idea
```

it seems to work, and doesn't seem to complain about not being able to find the dependency or anything - so I assume it gets it from nexus.

Anyways, when I try to build - I get the following error.

```
Kotlin: Unresolved reference: dependency
```

Adding a tag for intelliJ - in case this is some silly syncing issue... in case anyone is wondering...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, I am using the gradle build file - I am just using gradle clean idea to clear the project down, and then I am trying to build, and I am getting this error...

Comment: File a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KOTLIN with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Comment: It probably isn't a bug in Kotlin - this is probably my own problem