# How to make idea plugin in gradle generate proper project configuration for Kotlin?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I have configured my `build.gradle` to run `gradle test` and `gradle run` properly. However, IDEA does not show any `run/test` tasks after importing the configuration generated by `gradle idea`. It seems that these tasks are not included at `ipr`/`iws` at all.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0'

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
}

sourceSets {
    test.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
}

junitPlatform {
    enableStandardTestTask true
}

defaultTasks 'run'
mainClassName = 'simpledb.server.Startup'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/" }
}

dependencies {
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.2'
        testRuntime (
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.2',
            'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.2'
        )
        testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I was wondering is there any way to make generated project configurations include these tasks(`run`/`test`)? I have also heard people saying [Don't use gradle idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499617/how-to-import-build-gradle-into-intellij/42518961#42518961), so is it impossible to use `gradle idea` to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply not necessary in your case. Just open the build.gradle file with IDEA and everything should be smooth. The `idea` Gradle plugin is somewhat deprecated. Not officially, but it was created by Gradle team and is not actively developed to adapt to new IDEA versions and features and so on. So if you don't need special customizations, just open the `build.gradle` with IDEA and you should be good to go.